# C# Start EXE with Parameters and Save

Tags: c#, exe, param

At the moment I start a EXE-File so:

```
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.FileName = "Stackoverflow.exe";
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"] + name + @"\bin";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

If i want to add Parameters , I would do it here right?:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo, params);
```

If not, where?

And the other thing is, that I would like to save the params for the exe, does it happen automatically or do I have to set this, while opening? If so, then how I could achieve that?

EDIT:

What I mean with save is.. 
I got a Form with Textbox, from there u can start a EXE, by example Stackoverflow.exe and in the Textbox u could write: "-hello" , now next time u open the form and select the EXE in the FORM, there is "-hello" still written, that means, it has been saved, thats what I want

Comment: Yes...If you want to save which parameters were used you would have to do that yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) property. It's just a string of space-separated arguments. You'll need to quote any path names which include spaces, etc. It's a bit of a pain, but that's what's there :(

It's not really clear what you mean by "saving" the parameters - nothing will remember the arguments you last used to start a process and apply the same things next time, no. You'd have to do that yourself. How you do that will depend on what else you're doing - you could use a per-user setting, for example, the same way as any other setting.

Comment: @eMi: Right - that's completely orthogonal to how you start a process. That's just a matter of saving user settings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx

Comment: ok, that means, that I would save thet anywhere else.. ok thx 4 your answer

Comment: @eMi: I don't really know what you mean by "I would save thet anywhere else" - but basically what you do with the data in your UI is completely separate from launching a process.

Comment: maybe in txt File or XML, because, like u said, I can't save this in the ProcessStartInfo for ever, cause the user must write it always manually

Comment: @eMi: Right, yes - but if you use the built-in settings handlers for .NET, it's relatively easy.

Comment: And how I use them? Which u mean?

Comment: but does this save the settings, even when the user restarts the application?

Comment: @eMi: From the first sentence in the page: "The .NET Framework 2.0 allows you to create and access values that are persisted between application execution sessions." So yes.

Comment: Wow, then this is quite powerful, i mean this i like a small database ^^ , thx 4 your help, sry I'm only 15 and learning C#, I didnt really understand what this meant "The .NET Framework 2.0 allows you to create and access values that are persisted between application execution sessions" :D

Comment: That thing with the user settings won't work for me, cause I have to Create new Rows (new Settings) and Delete on Runtime, but  I only can change values of an existing Row/Setting... That means I must therefore still do it in a Textfile or XML or DB ...

Comment: @eMi: Okay, then that's going beyond what you've shown - you've been talking about a form with a textbox, and that's presumably known at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, that was just an Example... I did now a XML File, which I change Dynamically from my Code, but thx anyway for showing me this possiblity, its surely useful when developing other applications ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass arguments in the second argument to the Process.Start method. Ie:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");
```

Alternatively you can use ProcessStartInfo. I.e:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

There are some other useful examples in [msdn's class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You would set arguments in `processStartInfo.Arguments`.

I don't know what you mean by saving them, but it won't do anything as it's just a string. You can do whatever you want with this string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) property in your `ProcessStartInfo` class.

Also, the arguments will not be saved and why should they? If you create a shortcut on your desktop, then these arguments are stored there and your executable will be called with the stored arguments, but that has nothing to do with your application.